# Elements not being picked up by the code editor

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colors, border, transition

I have two elements which does not seem to be working/getting picked up by the development editor.

transition: border-color 3s ease-in-out; = Border-color is not getting picked up. I have pretty extension installed and it is coming up as invalid. same for --yellow in the next set of code. I have looked high and low and can not find

```
#login-form input{
    border:none;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    font-size:18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-bottom:25px;
    transition: border-color 3s ease-in-out;
}

#login-form input::placeholder  {
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#login-form input:focus {
    border-color: var(--yellow);
}
```

Comment: 1. That is a superuser question. 2. It would be super useful to include the IDE's name, version and platform

Comment: @mplungjan apologies for the inconvenience. IDE is Vscode, version is the latest and what do you mean by platform? I am currently using windows if that helps.

Comment: @mplungjan I changed to host as well but it seems to be the same. I can link my github in here if that helps

Comment: I cannot recreate in an HTML file or CSS file https://imgur.com/a/WAFCvOh

Comment: thank you so much, I have linked my github repository below.

Comment: https://github.com/Helllper/koko_clone_April_2023

Comment: I see a missing margin here: `body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    margin: 
} 
`

Comment: Sweet, thanks bro @mplungjan the editor do not seem to be picking up the "border-color " but the code works so I decided to move forward... its weird because I automaticly thought that the editor is showing it as invalid element because it will not work..

Comment: It could be your linter setting. I see `There is support for CSS version <= 2.1, Sass version <= 3.2 and Less version <= 2.3.` according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css but that could be old.

Comment: I could not find any information why transitions should be CSS2 and not only CSS3